# Objective C Drawing free form shape on top of image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, draw

I am working on a iOS 5 iPhone project where users can choose an image on their device, then trace an object inside of the picture (trace an apple out of a picture of a fruit basket), and then the picture needs to be uploaded with the "tagged" object so it can be pulled down later. Other people will then pull down the image and try to find where the tagged object is in the picture (Think "Where's Waldo?").

I have been trying to figure out the best way of tracing the object. Before, I had a user press the top left, top right, bottom left, and bottom right points around the object and create a square view around the object. The info for that view was uploaded and then pulled down for the user to find the object. The downside is that all objects are obviously not squares/rectangles so I need to do a free form shape.

I was thinking of allowing the user to draw over the object and then somehow I need to be able to tell what is inside of the trace (For example, inside of a circle that they traced), but a problem I forsee is making sure the trace they made is closed so I can fill in the shape (which is a whole not problem).

Any advice welcome on the best way of starting this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UIBezierPath](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html) might be a very useful friend here. It allows you to create any shape you need, and it supports both drawing and hit-detection. I recently did an implementation for a storybook where I could trace out a shape with their finger, freeze it, and then use the shape for tap detection.

The basic idea is this:

When your finger touches the screen, start recording positions. Discard any positions that are too close to the previous position (eg, only record a point if it is >min-distance from the last recorded point). While doing this, you can draw the UIBezierPath so you can see what you are tracing out. Modify the UIBezierPath by adding points to it, instead of recreating it every time.* When you lift your finger, close the bezier path. Quite simple.

Now, this will result in a polygon (ie, straight edges). *If your min-distance is low enough or if you are using it for hit-detection (as you say)*, it won't really matter. However, if you want to smooth the path, you have to use the curve-to methods, which slightly complicate it - but should you wish to follow up on this more, read up on splines and spline generation from a point series.

*note: otherwise you'll get lag while drawing large shapes because recreating a bezier path from an increasingly large series of points gets expensive. Modifying the existing path makes it much, much, much faster.

Comment: This sounds perfect. Thanks for your quick response!